# Unix find line number of a string in a file using awk/grip

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to find a position of a string

```
awk -F : '{if ( $0 ~ /Red Car/) print $0}' /var/lab/lab2/rusiuot/stud2001 | tail -l
```

and somehow I need to find a line position of Red Car. It is possible to do that using awk or grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
awk '/Red Car/ {print NR}' /var/lab/lab2/rusiuot/stud2001
```

This will print the line number for the line with `Red Car`

---

If you like the line number to be printed at end of the file:

```
awk '/Red Car/ {a[NR]} 1; END {print "\nlines with pattern";for (i in a) printf "%s ",i;print ""}' file
```

Comment: But I also need to print that line where Red Car is found.

Comment: @user3334375 This will just mark the lines:  `awk '/Red Car/ {$0=NR"-->"$0}1' file`.  Or do you like to print all line number at the end of the file, see updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
grep -n "Red Car" /var/lab/lab2/rusiuot/stud2001 | cut -d":" -f 1
```

-n option will display the line number along with line where pattern is found.